# How to move a postgresql backup from a server to a local machine?

Tags: postgresql, openshift

Currently I am creating a backup just by using "pg_dump dbname > path" in the pod terminal but this only saves it into the OpenShift container.

How would I transfer the dump to a local device?
Is there a a command for grabbing a database backup and downloading it onto the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oc cp` to copy files from a container to the local machine:

```
# Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally
oc cp <some-pod-name>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

So for example:

```
oc cp postgresql-1-ptcdm:/tmp/mybackupfile /home/myusername/mybackupfile
```

Note that this requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'oc cp' will fail. For advanced use cases, such as symlinks, wildcard expansion or file mode preservation consider using `oc exec`.

Comment: `oc rsync` is a nice alternative as well